# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'startswith'

Tags: python, pygal

```
import requests
import pygal
from pygal.style import LightColorizedStyle as LCS, LightenStyle as LS


url = "https://api.github.com/search/repositories? 
q=language:python&sort=stars"
r = requests.get(url)

response_dict = r.json()

names,stars = [],[]
for repo in repo_dicts:
    names.append(repo["name"])
    stars.append(repo["stargazers_count"])

my_style = LS("333366", base_style=LCS)
chart = pygal.Bar(style=my_style, x_label_rotation=45, show_legend=False)
chart.title = "Most starred Python projects on GitHub"
chart.x_labels = names

chart.add(" ", stars)
chart.render_to_file("repo_visual.svg")
```

When running this code I get an AttributeError.
I am trying to plot the python projects with the most stars onto a bar graph using the pygal module. The task is from Python crash course by Eric Matthes. I am cross-checking my code with his and I can't seem to find any problems

trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/user/PycharmProjects/generatingdata/python_repos.py", line 
51, in <module>
chart.render_to_file("x.svg")
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! It usually helps to include the stack trace, so that which line is causing the error is obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@SagarJhamb your code have two faults 
1.repo_dicts is not initialised
2. defining my_style= LS("333366", base_style=LCS) the value should start with **#333366** for learning more about custom style with pygal you can check out[pygal documentation][1][1]: http://www.pygal.org/en/stable/documentation/parametric_styles.html

```
import requests
import pygal
from pygal.style import LightColorizedStyle as LCS, LightenStyle as LS


url = "https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=language:python&sort=stars"
r = requests.get(url)

response_dict = r.json()
# initialise response dict
repo_dict=response_dict['items']

names,stars = [],[]
for repo in repo_dict:
   names.append(repo["name"])
   stars.append(repo["stargazers_count"])
# #333366 remove your error of NoneType object has no attribute startswith
#It is rightformat of using custom style with pygal
#It should starts with #
my_style = LS("#333366", base_style=LCS)
chart = pygal.Bar( style=my_style, x_label_rotation=45, show_legend=False)
chart.title = "Most starred Python projects on GitHub"
chart.x_labels = names
chart.add("stars", stars)
chart.render_to_file("repo_visual.svg")
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! repo_dicts is initialised I just forgot to include that part of the code in my post as it was part of the early program. I totally forgot about the # symbol infront of the RGB values. Including that worked, thanks again.